# How to push data to a mongoose array in collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm creating a CronJob to update every `key` from my `currencies` collection every 00:01. This is my `currencies` colection schema:

```
const CurrencySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    currency: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    exchange_rate: {
        type: SchemaTypes.Double,
        required: true
    },
    spread: {
        type: SchemaTypes.Double,
        required: true,
        default: 0,
        select: false
    },
    lastUpdate: {
        type: Date
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    history: [{
        date: Date,
        rate: SchemaTypes.Double
    }]
});
```

I tried to create a CronJob like this:

```
const CronJob = require("cron").CronJob;
const currencies = require("../../models/currencies");

module.exports = new CronJob("* 1 0 * * *", async function() {
    await currencies.find({}).map(currency => currency.history.push({
        date: Date.now(),
        rate: currency.exchange_rate
        })
    )
});
```

So, for every `currency`, I want to `push` to the `history` array the `Date.now()` and the `exchange_rate` of the currency at that moment.

The problem is that I get this exception:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'push' of undefined

How should I fix it?

Thanks!

Edit: a `console.log(currency)` inside the map function shows this:

```
[
  {
    _id: 5cbdefd4f5bcec257fcec791,
    currency: 'VES',
    exchange_rate: 5321.709437805213,
    createdAt: 2019-04-22T16:46:12.350Z,
    __v: 0,
    lastUpdate: 2019-05-15T20:40:08.649Z,
    name: 'Venezuelan Bolivar',
    history: []
  },
  {
    _id: 5cbdf078f5bcec257fcec792,
    currency: 'BTC',
    exchange_rate: 7290,
    createdAt: 2019-04-22T16:48:56.182Z,
    __v: 0,
    lastUpdate: 2019-05-15T20:41:01.122Z,
    history: []
  },
  {
    _id: 5cbe1ebccd6e6a2b4738070d,
    currency: 'BRL',
    exchange_rate: 4.2382007085048015,
    createdAt: 2019-04-22T20:06:20.796Z,
    __v: 0,
    lastUpdate: 2019-05-15T20:41:02.817Z,
    name: 'Brazilian Real',
    history: []
  },
  {
    _id: 5cbe1ec8cd6e6a2b4738070e,
    currency: 'INR',
    exchange_rate: 78.43526089163238,
    createdAt: 2019-04-22T20:06:32.322Z,
    __v: 0,
    lastUpdate: 2019-05-15T20:41:02.814Z,
    name: 'Indian Rupee',
    history: []
  },
  {
    _id: 5cbe1ecfcd6e6a2b4738070f,
    currency: 'ZAR',
    exchange_rate: 15.984316920438957,
    createdAt: 2019-04-22T20:06:39.513Z,
    __v: 0,
    lastUpdate: 2019-05-15T20:41:03.135Z,
    name: 'South African Rand',
    history: []
  },
  {
    _id: 5cbe1ed9cd6e6a2b47380710,
    currency: 'ARS',
    exchange_rate: 50.264175514403284,
    createdAt: 2019-04-22T20:06:49.520Z,
    __v: 0,
    lastUpdate: 2019-05-15T20:41:04.134Z,
    name: 'Argentinian Peso',
    history: []
  }
]
```

So I assume another array is being created, instead of returning each individual object

Comment: What does the currency object look like in the map function?

Comment: Well something has gone wrong grabbing the `history` array from your currency model, since that's what is undefined. Can you share the currency data with us?

Comment: `console.log(currency)` in map function gives an array with objects of every key

Comment: You need to add that kind of detail into your question, as an edit - show the contents of your models please. You've not given us enough details to work with in your question at the moment.

Comment: Sure, sorry. Doing it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Mongoose Update API](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update), the correct syntax should be:

```
await currencies.find({}).map(currency => currencies.update({ "_id": currency._id},
  { "$push": { "history": { date: Date.now(), rate: currency.exchange_rate } } },
  function (err, raw) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log('The raw response from Mongo was ', raw);
  }
));
```

Updating based on new information. May need to explicitly return the Mongoose calls and could definitely be refactored:

```
await currencies.find({}).map(currencyList => { 
  currencyList.forEach(currency =>  {
    currencies.updateMany({ "_id": currency._id},
      { "$push": { "history": { date: Date.now(), rate: currency.exchange_rate } } },
      function (err, raw) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        console.log('The raw response from Mongo was ', raw);
      }
    )
  })
});
```

Comment: This returns a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: currency.update is not a function`

Comment: Try replacing `currency.update` with `CurrencySchema.update`. You may need to export `CurrencySchema` explicitly or import it differently into the file you're working in.

Comment: I tried to change to `currencies.update`, which is my `CurrencySchema`, this didn't give me errors, however the return of the `raw` is `{ n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }`, I think because the `map` returns an array, and not object by object

Comment: I see you posted the output of your console log and 'currency' is your whole document, not just a single instance as I assumed. So maybe you need [updateMany](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateMany)

Comment: Perfect, that was it! Thanks a lot